# using an if/then in a repeater in an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, webforms

I haven't used asp.net webforms in what seems like forever, and I am having the toughest time figuring out how to get a simple if/then statement to work.  This is what I *want* to do:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" DataSourceID="lds">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% if(Eval("show")) { %> show something <% } %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

But obviously that gives me an error - how do I do this?  Thank you - I have completely gone to MVC now and I can't seem to remember this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an ItemTemplate

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" DataSourceID="lds">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("show") ? Eval("Whatever") : Eval("Whatever") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Comment: I just forgot to copy that down, but you are correct here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the conditional operator

```
<%= Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("show")) ? "something" : "" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a simple string or something, you can do this:

```
<%# bool.Parse(Eval("show")) ? "show something" : null %>
```

What exactly are you trying to show/not show?